# How to put " <" to this CASE WHEN expression?

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL this is a valid query:

`SELECT case 2+2 when 1 then 2 else 3 end`

If I put a complex subquery instead of '2+2' it still works well. But how can I change this query if i want to know if the result is *smaller* than a specific number?

For example this one doesn't work:

```
SELECT case 2+2 when > 1 then 2 else 3 end
```

Comment: For reference: [documentation on `CASE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two forms of the CASE statement in SQL, [described in the PostgreSQL manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE).

One, which you are using, compares a particular expression to a series of values, like a `switch` statement in C or PHP:

```
CASE something WHEN 1 THEN 'hello' ELSE 'goodbye' END
```

The other is a more general set of branching conditions, like an `if-elseif-else` sequence, or PHP's `switch(true)`. The above can also be written like this:

```
CASE WHEN something = 1 THEN 'hello' ELSE 'goodbye' END
```

So to use any comparison other than `=`, you need the "if-like" version. In your example:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 2+2 > 1 THEN 2 ELSE 3 END
```

Answer (score 0):

`select case when 2+2 > 1 then this else that end`